# Laravel relationship many-to-many incorrect return count

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a User model that applies both for trainers and studenst. In my business logic Trainers have students assigned for a certain Unit, so i built a many-to-many relationship among them

```
public function students()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'trainer_student',  
    'trainer_id','student_id');
}

    public function trainers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'trainer_student','student_id', 'trainer_id');
}
```

Both in the User model. I checked the DB and there are 8 students related to a trainer for a certain Unit.

["trainer_student" Table Photo](https://ibb.co/kkS2B7).

So i did this query with Tinker:

```
$trainer = User::findOrFail(21);
$trainer->students()->pluck('id');
```

[Output](https://ibb.co/nvnG4S).

But if i query like the usual way:

```
DB::table('trainer_student')->where('trainer_id',21)->pluck('student_id')
```

[Output](https://ibb.co/fx80W7).

What is going on? Why the relationship shows less students? What am i doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the columns are backwards for your relationship. Try the student id first, then the trainer id.

Comment: `student_trainer` would follow eloquent naming conventions, however, the pivot table name is being supplied correctly via `trainer_student` so that shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: What's the result of `$trainer->students()->toSql()`?

Comment: On a separate note, you should probably be doing: `User::with('students')->findOrFail(21);` to eager load those students.

Comment: Do you have foreign key constraints on? Are you sure those users exist in the database? I see they exist in the join table but what about in the user's table?